# jxbrowser not getting focus on MacOSX with SWT integration

Tags: eclipse, macos, swt, jxbrowser

After integrating the jxbrowser as an IViewPart in eclipse, the browser is not taking any focus on MacOSX. However, there is no issue with Windows and Linux with the same integration. I am not able to type type or click in the browser.

There is error in the console when I open the browser,

```
04:40:12 SEVERE: Failed to get and send screen id to Chromium. Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getContentView
```

And there is exception generated from BrowserView(Container).addNotify() line: 2773

Is this issue related to this post?
https://groups.google.com/a/teamdev.com/forum/#!topic/jxbrowser-forum/CgGX76sHfCA

Where do I go to see the status of JXB-1484?

Comment: The reason of this error message is that Swing container cannot get native window handle when it's embedded into SWT frame. Even if this message appears, it doesn't affect focus functionality. It looks like the issue is in SWT_AWT bridge on Mac OS X where keyboard/mouse events are not dispatched to Swing component embedded into SWT frame. You can check that by embedding a simple JTextField into SWT and try typing in it.

Comment: It looks like that is the case. Do you know whether there is any workaround to enable jxbrowser for MAC?

Comment: The issue isn't in JxBrowser library. The issue is that SWT_AWT bridge doesn't work properly on Mac. I don't know whether it's a known issue in SWT_AWT bridge or not. I haven't investigated this issue yet, so it's hard to suggest a workaround. You can try using only lightweight rendering mode and enable multi-process architecture via "jxbrowser.ipc.external=true" JVM parameter on Mac and see if it helps.